# PostgreSQL planner with join lateral (big and small table)

Tags: postgresql, query-performance, lateral-join

It is my belief that these two queries have the same output

my question is why doesn't the planner test both variants and pick the most efficient one?

```sql
select n.id, n.n <-> hc.n hdist_n, hc.*
from n 
join lateral (select * from hotelscombined hc order by n.n <-> hc.n limit 5)hc on (hc.cc = n.u) 
order by 1;
```

```sql
select n.id, n.n <-> hc.n hdist_n, hc.*
from hotelscombined hc                     
join lateral (select * from n order by n.n <-> hc.n limit 5)n on (hc.cc = n.u) 
order by 1;
```

```
                                                        QUERY PLAN                                                         
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Nested Loop  (cost=0.71..2466952.10 rows=515552 width=83)
   ->  Index Scan using n_pkey on n  (cost=0.43..1199539.45 rows=2181374 width=17)
   ->  Subquery Scan on hc  (cost=0.28..0.57 rows=1 width=75)
         Filter: (n.u = hc.cc)
         ->  Limit  (cost=0.28..0.51 rows=5 width=79)
               ->  Index Scan using hotelscombined_n_idx1 on hotelscombined hc_1  (cost=0.28..3906.32 rows=85687 width=79)
                     Order By: (n <-> n.n)
(7 rows)

Time: 4.814 ms
```

```
                                                 QUERY PLAN                                                  
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Sort  (cost=287016.55..287067.18 rows=20252 width=83)
   Sort Key: n.id
   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.41..285567.95 rows=20252 width=83)
         ->  Seq Scan on hotelscombined hc  (cost=0.00..2027.87 rows=85687 width=75)
         ->  Subquery Scan on n  (cost=0.41..3.30 rows=1 width=17)
               Filter: (hc.cc = n.u)
               ->  Limit  (cost=0.41..3.24 rows=5 width=3749)
                     ->  Index Scan using n_n_idx1 on n n_1  (cost=0.41..1231791.79 rows=2181374 width=3749)
                           Order By: (n <-> hc.n)
(9 rows)

Time: 7.817 ms
```

Comment: I don't know that those are identical.  It would not be a trivial thing to prove.  And testing both would take as much time as the longest one, which would rather defeat the purpose.  Now it could conceivably launch both, then return the first and cancel the other.  But that would waste resources that could be used by other tasks.